# MongoDB Search by property name for any Document with that property

Tags: mongodb

How do I do a search in MongoDB that searches for any documents with a given property?

What I want to do is find all the documents that have the property regardless of it's value and I don't seem to be able to do this.  I've tried the following

```
db.collection.find({"property", null}); //Finds things that don't have that property
db.collection.find({"proprety", {}}); //Doesn't find anything unless something has the empty object as the value
```

Is there actually a syntax for this or would I need to do a mapreduce operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just invert the query and search for documents where the property is not null ($ne not equals)

```
db.collection.find( { property : { $ne : null } } );
```

Comment: Having searched some more it looks like $exists also does the same job

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists
In the end of the page Mongo wrote Tip for "If you only need documents where the field has a non-null value"

Answer (score 10):

Here's the sample answer using $exists:

```
db.collection.find( { property : { $exists: true } } );
```